# Angular2+ ng2-smart-table: Get value of single cell when click Edit Button

Tags: angular, input, color-picker, ng2-smart-table

In my ng2-smart-table i have two column: 
`Description` and `Color`.

On column `Color` i have a `renderComponent` with implements an input with `type="color"` and on color change, it send to service the value of new color selected:

```
onColorChange(newColor: string) {
   this.data.changeColor(newColor);       
}
```

When I try to click `edit` button on any record, `ng2-smart-table` show me above the table, the color input with the wrong #000000.

I created this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnw27j for better explain my problem.

I want that when i click on `edit` button, on input with `type="color"` is selected the right color.

Can you help me? Thanks